# SQL Server import export data on localhost use network and get ASYNC NETWORK IO waits

Tags: sql-server, database, data-transfer

I have a problem with import/export of data on SQL Server, when I use localhost connection to transfer data between 2 databases on the same instance. This takes a long time to transfer data and when I check my activity monitor to find the problem, I see network resource waiting is the issue. Why?

It is set to use my connection on localhost and I expect the transfer to be done quickly for only 30 million rows.

I appreciate it if someone can provide some insights. Thanks.

I tried to change my connection providers, but the problem still remained.

Comment: Use `.` instead of `localhost` and enable Shared Memory protocol

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Shared memory was enabled and also i used dot instead of localhost. I also restart my sql service but the problem still remains.